# why json key shows a minus sign in its name when its assigned with a string number?

Tags: jquery, json, xml

hi i have the following xml converted to json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<category>
    <sports id="100">
        <indoor id="1000">
            <basketball id="100k" />
            <pool id="200k" />
        </indoor>
        <outdoor id="2000">
            <hockey id="300k" />
            <baseball id="400k" />
        </outdoor>
    </sports>
    <electric id="200">
        <entertainment id="3000">
            <tv id="500k" />
            <hifi id="600k" />
        </entertainment>
        <kitchen id="4000">
            <kettles id="700k" />
        </kitchen>
    </electric>
</category>
```

when i do this json shows a minus on the key "id" when it was assigned with a number

```
    {
  "category": {
    "sports": {
      "-id": "100",
      "indoor": {
        "-id": "1000",
        "basketball": { "-id": "100k" },
        "pool": { "-id": "200k" }
      },
      "outdoor": {
        "-id": "2000",
        "hockey": { "-id": "300k" },
        "baseball": { "-id": "400k" }
      }
    },
    "electric": {
      "-id": "200",
      "entertainment": {
        "-id": "3000",
        "tv": { "-id": "500k" },
        "hifi": { "-id": "600k" }
      },
      "kitchen": {
        "-id": "4000",
        "kettles": { "-id": "700k" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

why it shows a number? is this normal or should i modify "id" property not to have a minus?

Comment: We have no idea where or how you do this conversion. Please add full details and conversion code

Comment: @charlietfl i have used an online converter http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VrW4teYnJys

Answer (score 0):

That converter is using '-' for attributes prefix. Use this one instead, where you can choose which character you want for those prefixes: http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html